# TFS Build Dependencies

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

In TeamCity, you can create build dependencies where one build will not start until another finishes successfully.  Is that possible with TFS 2012?  Where can I find more information about how to set that up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that TFS doesn't have equivalent functionality, but you can achieve the same goals with a little work.

A common scenario I encounter is a team wants to do a build when they check-in that does some quick stuff (compile, fast unit tests), then immediately after wants to do another build that runs some slower stuff (integration tests, test deployments, etc).  I do this often with my teams, and I'll setup a Gated Build that runs in say 5 mins, then have a CI build that is kicked off as soon as the Gated Build checks-in, which may take an hour to run.  I like this approach as it gets the developers some feedback quickly, then more detailed feedback shortly thereafter.

Another supported scenario is having a build explicitly kickoff it's dependencies.  If you look a the Lab Build Template it does exactly this, it will first kickoff the application TFS Build, and the Lab Build will sit and wait for it to finish, then the Lab Build will continue.  In theory you could have Build A kickoff build B which kicks off C & D, etc.

If your needs are more complex than that (e.g. you have multiple applications that you have a build for each, then a Product that includes some applications that needs to be built after each application changes, then maybe a Product Suite build that needs to kickoff whenever a Product changes - this is the scenario I dealt with).  I basically implemented a custom build dependency system to handle this.  We made an XML file that described the build dependencies, then wrote a simple ISubscriber plug-in that we would deploy to TFS, and it would listen for Build Completed events then consult the dependency config and kickoff the appropriate build(s).